# SVN: Malformed XML error

Tags: svn

I am trying to checkout a branch from a remote repository. A number of files are checked out, then the checkout fails with the following errors:

svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML

svn: E130003: Malformed XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

What could have caused this issue and is there a way to repair the remote repository?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what steps lead to your error? Is there a reproducible example

Comment: I run a command line command svn checkout https://...  (cannot give you the repository url). I can see several files being checked-out (not all the files in the remote), then the checkout terminates with the above errors. I can see the checked out flies  in the file system with the svn status "locked". After running command line "svn cleanup" most of the files disappear from the files system. The ones left have svn status "!".

Comment: The remote is Apache Subversion version 1.7.22, the local is svn, version 1.9.4

Comment: The symptoms suggests the operation is being interrupted. It's possible that you may find further details in the log files of the Apache server that provides access to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the admin of the server for assistance with this problem. The root cause can be a malfunctioning antivirus on your workstation or on the server. Firewall or proxy could also cause such problems. Moreover, your server is outdated.

> The remote is Apache Subversion version 1.7.22

I guess that 'remote' means the remote server that hosts your repositories. SVN version that it runs is outdated. You must plan an upgrade to the latest 1.9.x version.

Comment: I tried contacting the admin, I couldn't get a response because I'm the admin and I don't know how to fix it!  I can browse the repository and even get update and checkout but commit gives me the same error as OP