# SVN Log file command

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, mod-dav-svn

when i run the SVN log -q command in SVN cli then we got below error.

```
r102892 | neeraja.gudiwada_xyz.com | 2017-05-09 12:40:05 +0530 (Tue, 09 May 2017)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r102891 | neeraja.gudiwada_xyz.com | 2017-05-09 12:36:17 +0530 (Tue, 09 May 2017)
SVN: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
SVN: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found at line 3507
```

any idea why we are getting this error.

@phd I have already see all related post but they are not elping to resolve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN: Malformed XML error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908950/svn-malformed-xml-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvn%5D+SVN%3A+E175009%3A+The+XML+response+contains+invalid+XML

Comment: @phd i have already see this question but it didnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Fresh hint](https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2018-02/0136.shtml) (external). If short:

you have to use URL, which can be used **without any redirects** at Apache-side. Web-browsers supports it, SVN - does not

Possible reasons

1. Misconfiguration of `<Location>` section in Apache's httpd.conf (I can't recall, have directory to **have** or **don't have** trailing / due to this problem, and haven't SVN-server now). BTW, recommended by SVN-book form is without trailing slash `<Location /svn>`
2. You used bad URL in `svn log`, which have to be "converted" to real (again, traling "/" problem). How to test it: use browser (web-brower) for accessing URL and identify URL, which give you result (after or without possible redirections). If this URL will differ from used in `svn log` - use correct form